# Detail page link under email template

Tags: customer-portal

I have a workflow which gets fired by a customer portal user and this in turns fires email alert notifying system admin user. I have created an email template for this. 
In which I use {!CustomObj__c.Link} to show record link so that system admin user can directly jump to detail page. But in the final email that is delivered to system admin, 
this link contains customer portal name i.e. https://idmaxi-1361.cloudforce.com/inventorportal/a0ab0000000PpiC
But I want it to be https://na9.salesforce.com/a0ab0000000PpiC.

What could be the reason?

Comment: It would be really helpful to forward this to Salesforce support.  Links in emails seem to be causing a lot of issues (sometimes visualforce domain, sometimes regulard domain, sometimes portal domain) these days and it would help if they knew about it

Answer (score 7):

I've used the following formula in Visualforce email templates to generate the server instance for a link:

```
Left($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_190,(find('/services',$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_190)))
```

Then I just concatenate the record id to this

Note: this was for eu server instances, though I can't see why the NA etc would cause a problem.

If this can't be used, due to an HTML template for example, you can create a custom formula field on the sobject, called Record Link or similar, as follows:

```
HYPERLINK(Left($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_190,(find('/services',$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_190))) + Id, 'Record Link' )
```

and then use that in the template.

If this is still pulling the custom web address, you may need to revert to the clunky mechanism of storing the server URL in a custom setting and use that in the email template.  The downside to this is that whenever you refresh a sandbox (for example) you'll need to fill in the custom setting anew.

So if I have a custom setting named 'URLS' and this has a field of 'Server__c', I can use this in the template as something like:

```
Direct Link: {!$Setup.URLS__c.Server__c + '/' + id}
```

Comment: As of now, I am having html template only not a visualforce template. I guess it will not work on that?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an option that should work for HTML templates).

Comment: I created a formula field that doesn't work too. It also generates url like https://idmaxi-1361.cloudforce.com/inventorportal/a0ab0000000PpiC

Comment: Hmm.  Clearly the custom URL sticks for the entire transaction. I've updated the answer with the old, clunky way of doing things.