# How to use Formula Operator in HTML Email Template?

Tags: email-template

I want to use certain Formula Opearator like

`HYPERLINK, LEFT, FIND` in my `HTML Email Template`. But I am not sure how to use that.

I tried using like below.

```
HYPERLINK({!Sobject.Link}, 'SOBJECT')
```

but outcome comes exact same way, it is written.

any idea?

Comment: have you looked at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8838/2602 ?

Answer (score 1):

The synxtax is a little different for HTML Email Templates. You need to add `{! }` around your formula field.

An example of this syntax using the `FIND` operator would be:

```
{! TEXT(FIND("o", "hello world")) }
```

To add on to this, your email template would most likely have text around it. Take for example:

```
The number is: {! TEXT(FIND("o", "hello world")) }
```

When sending a preview email to yourself, the formula will be evaluated. The email will contain:

> The number is: 5

You can use this for any formula operator (`LEFT`, `FIND`, etc.). Although you could use this method for the `HYPERLINK` operator as well, I would recommend just putting the hyperlink directly into the email template, since the formatting allows for HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Not all formula operators work in HTML Email templates

For example, you can use `IF` as in `{!IF(account.type = "foo","I am foo","I am not foo")}`

`LEFT` works as well as in: `{!LEFT(Account.Name,4)}`

HYPERLINK AFAIK does not work (at least I can't get it to render) but you can use this construction:

`Click here: {!Account.link}` - this is great for recipients who are also salesforce users but non-users wouldn't have access to the record

You can of course, for static links, use the HTML Email template editor toolbar

If the link is meant to be dynamic, use an sobject formula field that in turn uses Hyperlink, then reference the formula field in your email template. See https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h16fAAA

For example, if the Text Formula field value is `HYPERLINK("http://www.cnn.com","CNN")`

then the merge field on the email template is `{!Foo__c.Hyperlink_fld__c}`