# Formula field not showing any value in HTML Email template

Tags: email, formula, email-template, formula-field

I have a formula field, in which I refer a check box and if checkbox is checked it displays yes else no.
When I'm referring that formula in my HTML Email template, its not showing any value, It's always blank, but in the Plain Text Preview it shows value.

Comment: It's possible there's an issue with formulas in email templates, but as an alternative could you use an expression like this? `{!IF(My_Object__c.Checkbox__c, "Yes", "No")}`

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65441/how-to-use-formula-operator-in-html-email-template