# How to wrap record id as a link to the record while sending email

Tags: email, email-template, tasks, custom-link

I am writing trigger to send email to task owner after task got created.In the mail i  was sending recordId as a plain text.But i was trying is there any way to make the id as a link to the related record in salesforce.

the mail should be like

```
  Hello {task.OwnerId},

    A new {task.Id} was allocated for you.

Thanks,
User.Name.
```

this was a custom html mail here i am not using any html template.So i was wondering is there any way to do it in custom way like in standard html template we use `{task.Link}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detail page link under email template](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8837/detail-page-link-under-email-template)

Comment: While it may be a duplicate of *something*, it doesn't appear to be a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @crop1645  i was asking how to get this in apex but the link given is about email templates..  i might be wrong , thanks

Comment: sorry - i thought you were asking about templates - metadaddy below has the apex answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a link in a text email template, you can use `https://login.salesforce.com/{task.Id}` (or `https://test.salesforce.com/{task.Id}` in a sandbox) - if the user is already logged in, this will go straight to the Task; otherwise, it will take them to the Task via the login page. It also has the benefit of avoiding a direct reference to the instance (e.g. `na15.salesforce.com`), which can cause problems in the long term.

If you're generating the email text from Apex, you can use `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + task.Id` to achieve the same end.

Comment: Won't this break for sandboxes though?

Comment: Added the sandbox login link. I can't think of a generic way to do this that will work across both.

Comment: Since it's apex you could just get it programmatically with `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()`.

Comment: Question seemed to be about templates, but I added a note for Apex. Thanks!