# Merge field opportunity link of opportunity object is not populating in Email template

Tags: opportunity, admin

I am creating an Email template with case link and opportunity link.
case link working fine but opportunity link is not populating. 
Do any one know the reason and can help me in any ways ? 
If any one can help me asap it would be great.

Comment: Scenario :I have a scenario, I created a workflow for sending Email alert to a user, I created an Email template with case number, case link and opportunity name and Opportunity link using merge fields . when the email is sent all the details are displaying except Opportunity link (hyperlink). can any one help me with this if you know. little urgent. Thank you inadvance.

Comment: Can you share your email template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below.
replace xx with your instance

https://xx.salesforce.com/{!Opportunity.Id}

https://xx.my.salesforce.com/{!Case.Id}

Answer (score 0):

If the workflow target object is `Case`, only the `{!Case.Link}` merge field will populate. Related object detail links are not supported as merge fields

Assuming Case has a lookup relationship to Opportunity, you'll need to manually construct the link by [following Bob Buzzard's tips](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8838/2602)

e.g.

```
{!Left($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_360,(find('/services',$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_360))) & 
Case.Opportunity__c}
```

slightly different construction if using a VF email template

```
{!Left($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_360,(find('/services',$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_360))) & 
relatedTo.Opportunity__c}
```